# Hibernate InsertQuery does not generate identity on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a partitioned table in Postgres and I use a trigger to insert to partitions. And to avoid insertion on parent table I return null in the trigger.

On the other hand, hibernate needs to receive `affected count` when doing an insertion, but I am returning null from the trigger. To fix this problem, I am using `@InsertQuery()` with `ResultCheckStyle.NONE`;

And identity field in my entity is defined as:

`@Id
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;`

Now I get this error when doing insertion:
`database returned no natively generated identity value`

From what I read on Stackoverflow and other places this should work if the column in table is marked as auto increment. I use Postgres and id column definition is: 
`id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('transactionhistory.activities_id_seq'::regclass)`

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENC` works fine, but it need a separate sequence and I do not want to have two sequence on same column